# Can GLSL shaders be applied to SDL_Textures?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, sdl-2

I am working on a game and I would like to know if I can apply GLSL shaders to SDL_Textures without the need for OpenGL textures; and if so, how? I thought it may be possible because I am under the impression that SDL_Textures are just wrapped OpenGL ones.

Comment: Have a look at [SDL_GL_BindTexture](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_BindTexture) and similar functions. You _can_ work with the underlying OpenGL objects.

Comment: I'' give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, GLSL runs on the GPU, and therefore, the memory needs to be mapped on the GPU for it to be able to access and modify the texture. GLSL can only process OpenGL objects, since that is the way OpenGL was designed.

However, using a [PBO](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html), you can improve the time it takes to upload/download the texture to/from the GPU.